# Al subir mi aplicacion obtengo el error: "You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate"

Tags: android, angular, ionic, npm, google-play

Estoy generando una apk con las mismas credenciales con las que siempre he subido a la tienda de Google, pero ahora me aparece este mensaje ... Yo tenfo mi archivo keystore guardado y estoy seguro que es el mismo de siempre, pero obtengo el mensaje de error:

> You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate.
> You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has
> fingerprint: SHA and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded
> have fingerprint: SHA1:

La app esta desarrollada en ionic, comando ejecutado es `ionic cordova build --prod --release`  o también este `cordova build android --release -- --keystore=android.keystore --storePassword=**** --alias=**** --password=****`

Alguien podría aydarme a saber el por qué del error, o que ruta debo seguir?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La app que tratas de subir y la cual seguramente serìa una actualizaciòn, no fue firmada con el mismo certificado que la actual.

Siempre es importante que el certificado `.keystore` con el cual firmas tu aplicaciòn sea respaldado y guardado en un lugar seguro.

**Debes asegurar usar el mismo keystore con el cual firmaste la primera versiòn de la aplicaciòn.**

**Si perdiste tu certificado, afortunadamente en la actualidad puedes comunicarte con el equipo de soporte de Google para requerir tu certificado.**

> **Claves de carga perdidas o comprometidas**
> Si perdiste la clave de carga
> privada o esta se ve comprometida, puedes [crear una nueva](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423#create) y pedirle al
> propietario de la cuenta que [**se comunique con el equipo de asistencia
> para que la restablezca**](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs). Cuando lo haga, asegúrate de que adjunte el
> archivo upload_certificate.pem.
>
> Cuando nuestro equipo de asistencia haya registrado la clave de carga
> nueva, recibirás un correo electrónico y, luego, podrás actualizar tus
> almacenes de claves y registrar tu clave con los proveedores de API.
>
> Importante: La clave de firma de la app que usa Google Play para
> volver a firmar los APK antes de su entrega a los usuarios no se ve
> afectada cuando restableces tu clave de carga.

Revisa la documentaciòn oficial:

[Cómo usar la firma de apps de Google Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=es-419)